# How to display checkbox value (checked or unchecked )

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a project and the project was created with *ASP.Net mvc 5*.
I get the data from the database and I just want to display the data on the user interface. My problem is, I have all the data I want in the browser console, but the checkboxes are not shown checked. How can I do this?

```
"<input type='checkbox' value='" +item.IsActive+"'/>"
```

Here is my code:

```
    function success(data) {
        var rows;
        if (data != null) {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {       
                rows += "<tr>"
                    + "<td>" +
                    "<label class='checkbox-container' id ='checkbox-container'>" +
                    item.Name+
                    "<input type='checkbox' value='" + item.IsActive+"'/>" +
                    "<span class='checkmark'>"+"</span>"+
                    "</label >"+
                    "</td>"     
            });
            $('#myTable tbody').append(rows);
        }
        else {
            alert("Something went wrong");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set the `checked` property, not the `value` - although I presume they will need an actual `value` as well

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan. I've tried it now, unfortunately all checkboxes are shown as checked, although that's not true.

Comment: You use checked as checked="checked" or simply as check. When the checkbox is not checked, you shouldn't set this flag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some js logic would help?

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {       
    var checkbox_input = "<input type='checkbox' value='" + item.IsActive+"'/>";
    if(item.IsActive){
        var checkbox_input = "<input type='checkbox' value='" + item.IsActive+"' checked />";

    }
    rows += "<tr>"
        + "<td>" +
        "<label class='checkbox-container' id ='checkbox-container'>" +
        item.Name+
        checkbox_input +
        "<span class='checkmark'>"+"</span>"+
        "</label >"+
        "</td>"     
});
```

Or Shorthand with template literal js

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {       
    rows += "<tr>"
        + "<td>" +
        "<label class='checkbox-container' id ='checkbox-container'>" +
        item.Name+
        `<input type='checkbox' value='${item.IsActive}' ${item.IsActive ? 'checked' : ''} />` +
        "<span class='checkmark'>"+"</span>"+
        "</label >"+
        "</td>"     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a checkbox to show checked, it should have the checked attribute. In this case it would be something like:

```
 <input type='checkbox' checked/>
```

Since you have a variable that tells you wether the checkbox is checked or not, you could try using:

```
"<input type='checkbox'" + item.isActive ? "checked" : "" + "/>"
```

This will render the checkbox as checked when item.isActive is true.

Comment: Thanks for your support, but as a result I see this (undefinedcheckedcheckedcheckedcheckedcheckedcheckedcheckedcheckedcheedcheedededededck)